# Pusher Authentication with Meteor

Tags: meteor, pusher

Is there a way to setup pusher authentication for private channels using Meteor?  I looked in Atmosphere for a pusher package and didn't see one.

Answer (score 2):

After some digging the solution I found was not very difficult to implement.  Here are the steps.

1. `mrt add npm`
2. Add `"pusher": "0.1.3"` to `packages.json`
3. Add the following code block to a file INSIDE the `server` directory of your project.  Be sure to change the `appId`, `key`, and `secret` to be the correct ones for your app.

---

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {
  var Pusher = Meteor.require('pusher');
  var pusher = new Pusher( { appId: '12345', key: 'keytext', secret: 'secrettext' } );
  Meteor.Router.add('/pusher/auth','POST', function(){
    var req = this.request;
    var res = this.response;
    var socketId = req.body.socket_id;
    var channel = req.body.channel_name;
    var auth = pusher.auth( socketId, channel );
    res.write(JSON.stringify(auth));
  })
}
```